# Error message: Employee matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I have model Employee and same table in my local database. I need to have the possibility to edit any record and save it locally. When I have something in the webflow_id field I got this error when I tried to select the edit option: **Employee matching query does not exist.**
When I tried to edit record without this webflow_id it doesn't change, but creates a new record.

my views.py:

def staff_edit(request, webflow_id):

```
#employees = Employee.objects.all()
#print(employees)

if request.method == 'GET':
    if webflow_id == 0:
        form = EmployeeEditForm()
    else:
        try:
        #employees =  Employee.objects.get(pk=webflow_id)
            employees =  Employee.objects.get(pk=webflow_id)
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Employee DoesNotExist")
        form = EmployeeEditForm(instance=employees)
    return render(request, 'staffedit.html', {'form': form})
else:
    if webflow_id == 0:
        form = EmployeeEditForm(request.POST)
    else:
        employees =  Employee.objects.get(pk=webflow_id)
        form = EmployeeEditForm(request.POST, instance=employees)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('feedback:staff')
    context = {'form': form} #when the form is invalid
    return render(request, 'staffedit.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    webflow_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True, default=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('Role', through='EmployeeRole')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.webflow_id + " " + self.email + " " + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

this is my general html staff.html:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                     var data;
                     fetch("http://192.168.2.85:8000/fetchapi_employees/")
                        .then(response => response.json())
                        .then(json => data = json)
                        .then(() => {console.log(data); //this gave me Array of objects from my database
                            $('#datatable').DataTable( {
                            data:           data.employees,
                            deferRender:    true,
                            scrollY:        false,
                            scrollX:        false,
                            scrollCollapse: true,
                            scroller:       true,
                            "columns": [
                                { data: "webflow_id" },
                                { data: "first_name" }, 
                                { data: "last_name" },
                                { data: "email" }, 
                               
                                    { render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                        return '<a href="http://192.168.2.85:8000/staff/edit/' + row.webflow_id + '"><i class="far fa-edit fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                                        
                                    } },
                                    { render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                        return '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                                    } },



                            ],
                            "order": [[1, 'asc']]

                        } )
                        
                    })
                    } );
```

staffedit.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10.offset-md-1 mt-5">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Edit employee</h1>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="far fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

forms.py:

```
class EmployeeEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = [
            'webflow_id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'roles',
        ]
```

and this is my urls.py:

```
  path('staff/edit/<int:webflow_id>', views.staff_edit, name="staffedit"),
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?
Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webflow_id` is a `CharField`

> webflow_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=True)

Url parameter must be contain string:

```
path('staff/edit/<str:webflow_id>', views.staff_edit, name="staffedit"),
```

Also your **webflow_id** is not primary key. If you want to use it as primary key, you have to add `primary_key=True`.

```
webflow_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
```

I would also use **Try Except** for `get` method:

```
from django.http import Http404

try:
    Employee.objects.get(webflow_id=webflow_id)
except Employee.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404("Employee DoesNotExist")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fixed data type, I didn't noticed. But now when I tried to edit some record I got: Page not found (404)

Comment: @dev, you have to use `Employee.objects.get(webflow_id=webflow_id)`. Your **webflow_id** is not primary_key.

Comment: @dev, Also your `webflow_id` is not primary_key. If you want to use it as primary key , you have to `add primary_key=True`

Comment: Hi, I still got Page not found (404), I updated my models.py and the staff_edit function, Could you please take a look?

Comment: @dev, Have you changed your path to `path('staff/edit/<str:webflow_id>/', views.staff_edit, name="staffedit")`? Try to print  `webflow_id ` in your view, what see you then.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I changed, I just didn't update this part of my code in the question. I tried to print with Employee.objects.only('webflow_id') tell me if I'm doing wrong, I got QuerySet of all of my objects from database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227900/discussion-between-nksm-and-dev).